# Reduce repeated code in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a protocol that define some properties. My document class conforms with this protocol. For any other class I like to have these variables I set the document class to be the delegate so that I can write getter/setter in them like:

```
- (NSArray *)array
{
    if (self.delegate) {
        return self.delegate.array;
    } else {
        return [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
}
```

This way I have one place to store my stuff (no unnecessary copies) and I just ask my delegate until the chain reaches the document class. Problem: If I add a new variable to the protocol and would have to add the getter/setter everywhere! And since they all are the same I am asking for a way to *outsource* this repeated piece of code.

Comment: protocol that declares some variables... what???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to the problem of forwarding methods to a delegate is called "message forwarding" (not surprisingly) and is documented well here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

As you'll see when you read that page, the problem being solved there is astonishingly similar to the one you pose.

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to create a `category` on `NSObject` and include it where you need it. In that category,

- You can check if instance responds to `delegate` property getter selector,
- If it does, then dynamically perform the getter to get delegate instance.
- And then dynamically perform getter selector of property to get its value.

Here is how the code in `NSObject+Extentions.m` should look like:

```
@implementation NSObject (Extentions)

- (NSArray *)array {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
        id delegate = [self performSelector:@selector(delegate)];
        return [delegate performSelector:@selector(array)];
    } else {
        return [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
}

@end
```